# Very long running subprocess occasionally freezes indefinitely (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, spawn

I run a video encoding subprocess (mpv), the output is piped into another subprocess (ffmpeg), which packages the resulting media and sends it to an rtmp media server. This all takes place in a node.js app.

The app can run for many hours at a time, often 8-10 hours continuously without a single problem, however, sometimes it appears the mpv subprocess freezes without any error, log or warning, several hours into a job.

If I try running the same process and arguments in a commandline, I've yet to encounter this issue of freezing. This only seems to occur when spawned by the node app.

Increasing the spawn max buffer option or using an npm package for spawning called execa, but neither appears to help.

The most frustrating thing about this issue is the lack of any logs or errors when this occurs.
Usually I monitor the status of the app by checking the ffmpeg process stderr, which outputs a status line about once a second. As soon as it freezes, nothing is piped into ffmpeg so it stops outputting lines. Node.js, the video encoder and ffmpeg processes all produce their own logs, but none of them register any error when this occurs. It's as if someone presses a pause button on the mpv subprocess.
Although the subprocesses appear to freeze, the node.js app continues to 'work'. Killing the processes and restarting them within the app works and it will usually run for several more hours.

The lack of any errors leads me to believe it may be a long hidden bug in node.js's subprocess module, but I thought I'd double check before submitting a report.

I've been dealing with the issue for several months now. The app runs 4 times a week for periods of 5-10 hours and on average it inexplicably freezes like this once or twice a week. Very frustrating.

It would be great if I could finally understand why this occurs and how I could fix it.

Comment: This is why I ported my Node.js app to .NET Core. Node seems unreliable when you have long running tasks. Haven't had a single issue with it on .NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really an answer, but more of an "experience".
I also use video stream encoding (from rtsp IP camera) with ffmpeg.
only one ffmpeg process create a archive video file (by 15mn segment) and at the same time create the stream for the live in http HSL).

i have 3 IP Camera so 3 "spawn" (ffmpeg) on the same NodeJS app (the app run the web server too)
it works carefree for days and days.

If the link with the input stream is cut either it is managed  drectly by ffmpeg which awaits its return or via NodeJS which relaunches the process.

I therefore do not use "mvp" for that, and therefore no "pipe" *(I don't know if that can be the reason)*.

why do you need "mvp" for that kind of thing?
a simple ffmpeg process couldn't do the job?

Comment: I need to use mpv because i need to be able to change the playlist and media settings on the fly, ie, changing playlist order, enabling/disabling subtitles, setting the audio track, enabling/disabling filters. These features are absolutely necessary for my purposes, mpv is the only program that can do this (that I'm aware of)

Comment: Oki i see.  have you trying to use the same process but with option "shell: true" ? and anoher thing like calling a shell script with  "mvp pipe ffmpeg in it" ?  and use "strace" (and other system tools) to have some more information (if, like me, you run on Linux plateform)

Comment: I will try using shell:true. 
Running a single shell command mpv | ffmpeg seems a bit inappropriate, if I need to kill the subprocesses by force I first need to find their pids and then I can't unpipe mpv from ffmpeg, I will probably get epipe errors as a result.

Comment: you can get the PID when you spawn the process,  after using myprocess = spawn('cmd'), get it by:  pid = myprocess.pid, killing the shellscript will kill also mpv and ffmpeg